# Get Tailwindcss in Salesforce org

Tags: salesforce, tailwind-css, salesforce-lightning, lwc, aura-framework

I want get Tailwindcss into my Salesforce org, so that I can use those classes for UI requirements in LWC/Aura components, Searched online a lot but couldn't find anything, Help me with the steps?

Answer (score 0):

You must to get the tailwind css file(https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css), then you should upload as an static resource to the org.

You can add those styles from LWC using this code:

```
import resourceName from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/tailwind';
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

loadStyle(this, resourceName + '/tailwind.min.css')
```

Just to mention, using in that way:

- You can't customize Tailwind's default theme
- You can't use any
  directives like @apply, @variants, etc.
- You can't enable additional
  variants like group-focus
- You can't install third-party plugins
- You
  can't tree-shake unused styles